# scrollbar hidden behid the taskbar

Tags: html, scrollbar, hidden

I am facing an issue while developing a html page, as the vertical scroll bar is being hidden behind the task bar, I have attached the screenshot here, Please suggest me the possible solution for this.[image]

Comment: did you use any absolute or fixed position with a specific height and an overflow:hidden ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make the task bar set to always visible, 
if this thing still happening use full screen window.

Comment: no this is not required, I have fixed the header thats why somehow the dynamic content with scroll bar is being hidden, any other hard coded solution?

Comment: In my opinion, it has something to do with an height and an overflow hidden